# Google Sheets Query: Can I remove column header?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, google-query-language

Here is my formula:

`=QUERY('2021 Report'!E3:E76;"SELECT E, COUNT(E) GROUP BY E ORDER BY COUNT(E) DESC LABEL (E) 'COUNTRY'";0)`

[Here is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac53Q.png)

It's returning the **count** as header. I want just the numbers. Is there any way to remove this **count** header?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try (no headers)

```
=QUERY('2021 Report'!E3:E76,"SELECT E, COUNT(E) GROUP BY E ORDER BY COUNT(E) DESC label COUNT(E) ''",0)
```